# Does the game shown in the following picture have a particular name?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Does the game shown in the following picture have a particular name?

<sub>(I ask because a similar game does not exist in my country and I would like know its rules.)</sub>

[image]

Comment: There are several games being played there. They are named along the top of the table.

Comment: Phrase "not similar game exists" is unclear / incorrect.

Comment: @jwpat7: Could you explain why? Maybe I could clarify something about the phrase.

Comment: I can't explain because I don't know what you meant to say.  Phrase "because not similar game exists" is nonsense as is.  Try "because no similar game exists" or "because a not-similar game exists" or "because a similar game does not exist", depending on what you meant.

Comment: @jwpat7: Thank you. What you are saying is really helpfull to me because I'm not native. :)

Comment: Is this a game you're playing with other people, or is it a random image you found on the internet?

Comment: I was searching for grammatical forms on the internet while I came across that image. So, yes, we could say that that is a random image I found on the internet, but I do not see how that could assume relevance.  @Mitch

Comment: Looks like a scoreboard for multiple games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [princessliyana's blog](http://princessliyana1706.blogspot.com/2008/06/english-language-camp-seronoknya.html) for discussion of these English-language-camp activities, by a Cat Group member or facilitator (I don't know which), who wrote [according to [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com/#ms|en|Dari%20satu%20aktiviti%2C%20ke%20satu%20aktiviti.%20Spelling%20Bee%2C%20Last%20Letter%2C%20Text%20Reconstruction%2C%20Guessing%20Game%20dan%20aktiviti-aktiviti%20lain.%20Mereka%20participate%20dengan%20aktifnya.%20Aku%20paling%20suka%20aktiviti%20Tableau%20dan%20Drama.)] "From an activity, to an activity. Spelling Bee, Last Letter, Text Reconstruction, Guessing Game and other activities. They participate actively. I especially like Tableau and drama activities."

Anyhow, I suggest that the particular name of the
game shown in the picture is *English Language Camp*.

Answer (score 7):

My guess:  This is an elementary school classroom.  The children are divided into ten groups, called BIRD, GOAT, DUCK, and so on.  Each group will play each of six games called "Spelling Bee", "Last Letter", and so on.  They will get a numerical score for each game.  When all games have been played, the scores will be added horizontally and the sums written in the "Total" column.  Then some extra points may be added and written in the "Bonus" column.

But that is just a guess from the picture.

Comment: I think you're right in your guess. I know what spelling bee is, I suppose I can imagine what text reconstruction and drama may be, but could you help me understand what *tableau* is?

Comment: +1, I was a camp counselor a few years ago and we did lots of language games like these. *Last Letter* is a fun one (sometimes called *Caboose*) where one person says a word, and the next person has to name something that starts with the last letter of that word, and so on. We played it where each word had to be the name of a city. @Paola: Tableau, I think, is another name for *[Charades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charades)*.